# AFNetworking iOS - way to see actual data in NSLog after GET request is complete

Tags: ios, json, ajax, api, afnetworking

I have a simple call to an api method below called queryJobAndMoveWithName that makes GET request (ex. http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=jennifer).

However when I look at the log responseJSON gets rendered as <57652068 6f706520 746f206c 61756e63 68205353 4c206163 63657373 20746f20 616c6c20 70616765 73206f6e 20494d44 6220696e 20746865 20766572 79206e65 61722066 75747572 652e0d0a 0d0a5468 616e6b73 20666f72 20796f75 72207061 7469656e 63652e> other than  {XXX:XXX, XXX:XXX}

```
- (void)queryJobAndMoveWithName:(NSString *)name completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *resultsJSON, NSError *error))completionHandler {

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=%@", kAPIHost, kSearchPath, name];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/javascript" ,@"text/html", @"text/plain", @"text/json", nil];

    [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSON) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseJSON);
        completionHandler(responseJSON, nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        completionHandler(nil, error);
    }];
}
```

Here is a method that calls the api method from view controller

```
- (IBAction)searchButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",self.searchTextField.text);
    NSString *queryName = self.searchTextField.text;
    NSArray *fullName = [queryName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *formattedFullName = [fullName componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];

    FPAImdbApi *imdbApi = [[FPAImdbApi alloc] init];
    [imdbApi queryJobAndMoveWithName:formattedFullName completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *resultsJSON, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        } else if (resultsJSON) {
            NSLog(@"result json: \n %@", resultsJSON);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"nothing found");
        }

    }];

}
```

so my question is how do I view the contents of the resulting JSON in logs other than the form of memory

Answer (score 0):

You have not told the manager that the response is in JSON, here you set the response serializer to HTTP:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Chang it to JSON:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

In the error block you could do something like this to print out the response from the server:

```
if (error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *respone = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey];
    NSData *errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:errorData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
}
```

Comment: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Comment: Then the JSON you receive from the server is not valid, may be some API key that is not set? See my edit on how the handle the response incase of an error and out the data as a string to the log.

Comment: I'm hitting this end point no key required http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=jennifer

Comment: Then add the log code to your failure block, this will output the server response so you can get a better idea what is going on.

Comment: manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer =  [AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer];     is still returning set of hexadecimal numbers

Comment: You should not change the `requestSerializer`, since this will change thawed data is request form the server.

Comment: responseString is empty